# Meaning of "still" within "Do you mind if he testify still; before, you said you didn't care if Mueller testifies?"

Tags: interpretation

Does *still* within:

> Do you mind if he testify **still**; before, you said you didn't care if Mueller 
>   testifies?

means: *even though* ?

source: The reporter's question in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytyg1WtH0as&t=4m22s) interview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been better phrased as:

> Do you **still mind** if he testifies?

meaning "continue to mind".  Spoken questions don't always use the best sentence structure or grammar, but this is fine as long as the meaning is clear.

Comment: Could the sentence be considered ungrammatical?

Comment: @Norbert  No, just poor style if written.  An adverb should be close to the verb it modifies, otherwise it can be confusing.